# React router parametrized routes: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, react-router

I have a React-router set up which uses parametrized routes:

```
<Route path="/comments" comments={comments.commentsArray} component={NewReactElement} />
    <Route path="/comments/:id" component={Comment} />
```

The error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

I have researched the error, and found out it was happening when the server tries to get a .js/.css/other file, but is returned HTML beginning with `<!DOCTYPE>` instead, so I set up the `express.static`, but when entering URL such as `comments/1250`, it still returns: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`. This is my server setup:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/webpacked'));
app.listen(5000);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views', 'webpacked', 'index.html'));

 });
```

I have also tried:

```
app.use('/*/*', express.static(...));
```

But it did not work, either.

Thank you for advice in advance.

Answer (score 11):

I've got a react/react-router page without any express and got the same error:
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` which started to appear as soon as I configured a react route other then just root `/`.

After some experimenting I've figured out that in my index.html there was a link to js file:

```
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, the solution was to add `/` in the source path:

```
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the error has gone.

Hope that could help a bit.

Comment: Woah, It actually worked... I wonder why it works just fine without '/' when I access non-params routes

Comment: Thanks so much, this is THE ANSWER, i still wondering like Jakub Kopys the why of that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the `/` to `bundle.js` as [this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37949474/350382) the issue still persisted.

I was able to fix the issue by running `rm -rf .cache` in my project directory, as per this [github issue](https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react-v4/issues/3).