# ReactJS protected routes and nested routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I got a problem with my routes in `ReactJS`. I defined some routes like this :

```
...Import / Class...
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/user/contact" component={Contact} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/user/person" component={UserPerson} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/user/profile" component={Profile} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
...Export...
```

Below you can see my `ProtectedRoute`class

```
...Import / Class...
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        AuthGestion.userIsAuthenticated() ? (
            <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
            }}/>
        )
    )} />
);
...Export...
```

When I go to my page with a `<NavLink to="/user/person"></NavLink>`, there is no problem, my component is loaded and I can see my page.
But when I go to the url directly `/user/person`, and recharge my page (CTRL + F5), I got in the `Console` the error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` and a white page.
Just the user routes don't work.

I add below my server informations :

```
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import routes from './routes/index.route';
import config from '../../config/config';

import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackConfig from '../../config/webpack.config.dev';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';

//Connexion MongoDB
mongoose.connect(config.mongodbUri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => { console.log('MongoDB connecté'); });
mongoose.connection.on('error', (error) => { console.log(error); });

//Lancement serveur express
const server = express();

//Express need
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(express.static(config.publicPath));
server.use(express.static(config.distPath));

//Hot reload
if(config.isDevMode) {
    const webpackCompiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
    server.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpackCompiler, {}));
    server.use(webpackHotMiddleware(webpackCompiler));
}

// Route vers l'API
server.use('/api', routes);

// Landing page
server.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(config.publicPath, '/index.html'));
});

//Ecoute du serveur
server.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`App here : http://${config.host}:${config.port}`);
});

export default server;
```

Can you please help me to understand the problem ? And maybe correct my routing if it's not good.

Comment: Sounds like your server returns wrong payload on the internal route, If your app is managing the routes client-side, that means that all the routes that are requested from the server should serve the client code.

Can u share regarding your server?

Comment: I added my server informations. It is what you want ?

Comment: Do you get this error on the api request or on the html page itself?

Comment: I haven't any errors with my API, I got this error on the front side in the console, on the html page itself. I didn't call my API for the moment in the 3 components `user/contact`, `user/person`, `user/profile`

Comment: maybe the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/37949474/11129751

Comment: The question is if the error comes from the api call or on page load?

Comment: @Fraction you right, In my `index.html` I had `<script src="./dist/client.bundle.js"></script>`. I remove the dot ahead`/dist` and I got no errors anymore now... I don't know how this worked until today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37949474/11129751

> I've got a react/react-router page without any express and got the
>   same error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' which started to
>   appear as soon as I configured a react route other then just root /.
>
> After some experimenting I've figured out that in my index.html there
>   was a link to js file:
>
> So, the solution
>   was to add / in the source path:
>
> and the error has
>   gone.
>
> Hope that could help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This has changed since React-Router 6.

You CAN use nested routes/components with this syntax below.

```
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/public" element={<PublicPage />} />
      <Route
        path="/protected"
        element={
          // Good! Do your composition here instead of wrapping <Route>.
          // This is really just inverting the wrapping, but it's a lot
          // more clear which components expect which props.
          <RequireAuth redirectTo="/login">
            <ProtectedPage />
          </RequireAuth>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}

function RequireAuth({ children, redirectTo }) {
  let isAuthenticated = getAuth();
  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}
```

Comment: You can't try the same method for nested routes in react-router dom v6. this will end in throttling navigation, for the single route it is okay.