# React router nesting routes inside route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a problem with nesting routes inside route. User component has tabs and I want to display components based on URLs like this /profile/:userid/about and /profile/:userid/posts and /profile/:userid.

```js
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
   <Route path="profile/:username/*" element={<ProfilePage/>}/>
   <Route path="login" element={<Login/>}/>
   <Route path="register" element={<Register/>}/>
</Routes>
```

Profile routes

```js
<ProfileContentWrapper className='rightPanel'>
    <PorfileTabs/>
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/about' render={() => <ProfileAbout/>}/>
        <Route path='/posts' render={() => <ProfilePosts/>}/>
    </Routes>
</ProfileContentWrapper>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345851/react-router-parametrized-routes-syntaxerror-expected-expression-got

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full path in ProfileContentWrapper as well.

```
<Route path='profile/:username/about' render={() => <ProfileAbout/>}/>
<Route path='profile/:username/posts' render={() => <ProfilePosts/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found a problem in react-router v6 useRouteMatch is replaced with useMatch. In v6 I need to pass the route pattern to useMacht("profile/:username/")